# ¿Cómo habilitar módulo MySQL para Apache en Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, apache

He instalado MySQL y PHP en Ubuntu, para habilitarlos como módulos de Apache y así tener un LAMP. Si bien con PHP la forma de habilitarlo es a través de `a2enmod php7.2`, con MySQL, si uso este comando, ya sea `a2enmod mysql` o `a2enmod mysql-server`, me indica que el módulo MySQL no existe.

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo habilitar MySQL como módulo de Apache?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: enteoria deberias de ejecutarlo con el comando `systemctl status mysql.service` si quieres que se ejecute cada vez que ubuntu cargue tendras que hacerlo asi `systemctl enable mysql.service` esto te creara un archivo de configuracion. Cosa que siempre que el pc se encienda te activara el servicio.

Comment: Pero eso implica que está activo como módulo de Apache?

Comment: el Mysql es un servicio de base de datos desde consola puedes entrar y hacerlo funcionar, Apache solamente lo que hace es de servidor, no tiene nada que ver. En cambio si vas hacer cosas con PHP alli si que estas conectando al servicio del mysql, pero Apache solamente lo que realiza es ejecutar el PHP

Comment: Disculpa, pero como estoy empezando en esto, tengo que reconocer que no tengo mucha idea de lo que me estás comentando. Sin embargo, me parece que lo que me quieres decir es que Apache no interactúa con MySQL pero con PHP sí. El que interactúa con MySQL es PHP. Es por eso que MySQL no se puede configurar como un módulo de Apache ¿Más o menos va por ahí la cosa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento aquí mejor porque en comentario se vera demasiado largo...

Que es Apache y para que sirve ?

> Apache es un servidor web HTTP de código abierto. Está desarrollado y
> mantenido por una comunidad de usuarios, podrás ejecutar código en HTML, python, php, perl, ruby, etc...

Que es Mysql y para que sirve?

> Mysql es un servidor de base de datos, solamente sirve para almacenar datos. Cuando se combina con lenguajes que tienen programación del servidor (se pueden ejecutar desde Apache el lenguaje ) es una herramienta muy potente.

Por lo tanto Apache solamente es para poder cargar las web's que se realicen o proyectos con diferentes tipos de código y Mysql es para poder escribir, leer, eliminar y editar datos de las tablas que se creen.

Comment: Entendido. Muchas gracias Jordi :D